# Accessing ViewModel From multiple Views

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

So. In basis I have a ViewModel (VM), and I have three views.
All three views need to set their data context to the same view model.

The problem is the view model needs to return data to the view that called it.

The VM is supposed to get information from the database and load it into a data-grid in the first view when it calls for it. When the second view in instantiated, it will also need the VM to give it information to show in it's data-grid / textboxes

Now if I was only using one view then this would be sufficient:

```
// This is the ViewModel
class registrationSQL
{
    #region Declarations

    Medcare2.mascamainDataSet mascamainDataSet { get; set; }
    Medcare2.mascamainDataSetTableAdapters.signupTableAdapter mascamainDataSetsignupTableAdapter { get; set; }
    System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource signupViewSource { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    // I pass the user control into the constructor
    public registrationSQL(Medcare2.content.administration.registration.tabs.grid grid)
    {
        //  //Load your data here and assign the result to the CollectionViewSource.
        mascamainDataSet = ((Medcare2.mascamainDataSet)(grid.FindResource("mascamainDataSet")));
        // Load data into the table signup.
        mascamainDataSetsignupTableAdapter = new Medcare2.mascamainDataSetTableAdapters.signupTableAdapter();
        mascamainDataSetsignupTableAdapter.Fill(mascamainDataSet.signup);
        signupViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(grid.FindResource("signupViewSource")));
        signupViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then in the page's code behind I set the datacontext and tell it to pass itself onto the VM's constructor

```
// This is  the view's code behind.
public partial class grid : UserControl
{
    public grid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            // A new instance of LoginSQL is to be created and set as the current datacontext
            DataContext = new registrationSQL(this);
        }
    }
}
```

THis is the xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Medcare2:mascamainDataSet x:Key="mascamainDataSet"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="signupViewSource" Source="{Binding signup, Source={StaticResource mascamainDataSet}}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}" DataContext="{StaticResource signupViewSource}">

    <DataGrid x:Name="signupDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding}" EnableRowVirtualization="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="tagColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="tag" Binding="{Binding tag}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="firstColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="first" Binding="{Binding first}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="secondColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="second" Binding="{Binding second}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="thirdColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="third" Binding="{Binding third}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lastColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="last" Binding="{Binding last}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="genderColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="gender" Binding="{Binding gender}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dobColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="dob">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding dob, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="usernameColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="username" Binding="{Binding username}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="passwordColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="password" Binding="{Binding password}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="questionColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="question" Binding="{Binding question}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="answerColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="answer" Binding="{Binding answer}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="pemailColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="pemail" Binding="{Binding pemail}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="wemailColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="wemail" Binding="{Binding wemail}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cellColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="cell" Binding="{Binding cell}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="homeColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="home" Binding="{Binding home}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="extColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="ext" Binding="{Binding ext}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="streetColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="street" Binding="{Binding street}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="surbubColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="surbub" Binding="{Binding surbub}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cityColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="city" Binding="{Binding city}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="regionColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="region" Binding="{Binding region}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="deptColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="dept" Binding="{Binding dept}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="bankColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="bank" Binding="{Binding bank}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="branchColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="branch" Binding="{Binding branch}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="accountColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="account" Binding="{Binding account}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And that's all I'd need to do. But what if I want more than one user control to access the VM and return data to it? How do I get the VM's constructor to accept any window rather than just the one specified? Or any other method you can think up would be appreciated.

Comment: You are doing it in wrong way. in MVVM a **View** may know abt a **VM** but **VM** should not be bound to any **View**. Basically you should create a notifiable list in your VM which should have the data to be bound to any grid and each of the required View will set the data context to this ViewModel and set the data source as notifiable list in the VM.

Comment: Well not going to talk about design here. Usually you want to share a view model if the functionality that it provides is common to all that use the view model. Now assuming that the view model that you have is common to all then all you have to set the view data context to view model and your binding should just work as expected on whatever is consuming the properties (collections included). You will Inotifypropertychanged by the way.

Comment: @TYY in this case it is If I were to change the contents of the view  from a datagrid to a list, it would still function without me having to touch the views code. Thing is here I need a datagrid and form in completely separate pages.

Comment: One view <==> One view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you do it the other way round: In your Viewmodel, store the data that's coming from the database in an `ObservableCollection` or a similar generic object - the Viewmodel shouldn't care about how this data is presented (and which user control is used to present the data).

Speaking about the View: Simply pass an instance of the Viewmodel class to the window's `DataContext` property, and bind the DataGrid's `ItemsSource` to the collection that holds the data within the Viewmodel.

Using this set-up, it should not be a problem to re-use the same Viewmodel for multiple windows - just use the same Viewmodel instance for both window's `DataContext` properties! (Of course, this only makes sense if both windows shall present the same data...)

Comment: Okay so since I have no idea what an observable collection is, I did some googleing for a tutourial or two. They all seem to have binding in common but if you'll look at the additional code I just posted of the xaml, it already has bindings (and it's own static resource data context) Won't changing those break the functionality of the datagrid? The xaml code was purely written by visual studio itself when I dragged and dropped it onto the page.

Comment: Well, the XAML code looks fine. To make this work for both windows, I'd suggest you move the declaration of `<CollectionViewSource x:Key="signupViewSource" Source="{Binding signup, Source={StaticResource mascamainDataSet}}"/>` to the `App.xaml`'s resources instead of the UserControl's resources, because then you should be able to use the same Viewmodel instance for multiple windows / usercontrols /...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've just done this. It just leaves me with one question. How do I set the datacontext in the usercontrols? Do I pass anything on to the constructor still?

Comment: If the Viewmodel is declared as resource within the `App.xaml`, this means that a global instance of the Viewmodel class is created during App startup. To use this Viewmodel in a View (a UserControl, Windows, etc.) just user `DataContext="{StaticResource viewmodelInstance}"`, where `viewmodelInstance` is the declared resource's key.